# xpath: Find all ancestor by tag value (find all xhtml tables that have cell value)

Tags: php, xpath

I have a xhtml page with tables. Usualy one of them have text "needle text" in cell.
How to get all tables like that?

```
<table class="content_table">
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Value 11</td>
     <td>Value 21</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="link.html">needle text</a></td>
    <td>Value 22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** Table can be with tags: thead, th, etc.

1. Collect all tables from xhtml page - done with `"//*[@class='content_table']"`.
2. Locate node with text, but without success. I have tried with
   `//alink[text() = "needle text"]` but got empty result.
3. Find table as ancestor in parent of parent tree.
   `//alink[text() = "needle text"]/..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below **XPATH**

```
//a[.='needle text']/ancestor::table[1][@class='content_table']
```

or

```
//table[@class='content_table' and .//a[.='needle text']]
```

Comment: Both return empty result. Could be posible reason that table have thead, th, ... `<table class="content_table"><thead><tr><th><alink veza="5.html">needle text</alink>...`

Comment: Thanx for link, it is excelent. And your andswer work there for my original code. Have to find is it my php code ok.?.

Comment: Everithing works! I had \r\n after searched text. `<alink href="link.html">needle text[NEW LINE]</alink>`. Solved with ...`.//alink[contains(.,'needle text')]]`. Best Regards, Thank you wery much!